# D3D12EnableExperimentalFeatures causes D3D12CreateDevice to fail

Tags: directx12, directx

I am following [Nvidia's DXR tutorial: D3D12HelloTriangle](https://developer.nvidia.com/rtx/raytracing/dxr/DX12-Raytracing-tutorial-Part-1). I call below code before creating device and it returns **true**

```
UUID experimentalFeatures[] = { D3D12RaytracingPrototype };
HRESULT hr = D3D12EnableExperimentalFeatures(1, experimentalFeatures, NULL, NULL);
```

But this causes later for `D3D12CreateDevice` to fail. I am using Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050  :

```
 Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
       Chip type: GeForce GTX 1050
        DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
     Device Type: Full Device
      Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8D&SUBSYS_12651025&REV_A1
   Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER] 
  Driver Version: 23.21.13.8873
     DDI Version: 12
  Feature Levels: 12_1,12_0,11_1,11_0,10_1,10_0,9_3,9_2,9_1
    Driver Model: WDDM 2.3
```

Comment: The value of the HRESULT you're getting should shed some light on the reason.